# NumberFormat.format() returns inconsistent values

Tags: java, multithreading

I am parsing multiple files in parallel, and from times to times, the format() method will not return the right value.

```
Number parse = numberFormat.parse(val);
String format = numberFormat.format(parse);
format.equals(parse); //returns false sometimes
```

- At first I thought it was due to the fact that the format method was not thread safe, but it was using a `numberformat.clone()` for each thread.

I also tried creating a `new NumberFormat()` for each thread, and also a `ThreadLocal<NumberFormat>`, with an initial value, and then calling the `get()` method, all with the same problem.

- In the debugger, an evaluation of the expression always return the right value at the breakpoint.
- I tried putting multiple lines `String format = numberFormat.format(parse);`, it turns out that randomly, one or several of the lines return a completely wrong value, and the other return the right one.

I'm 99% sure it's a thread issue, and a concurrent access is made to something, probably the numberFormat itself.

I might not have used the right way to make it thread safe, but in my understanding, using either `clone()` or `new` should get rid of that concern.

Any clues as to what is causing the issue, and how to fix it?

EDIT :

Here are two screen shots made with IntelliJ IDEA to showcase the issue :

[image: 1st test case, two format are wrong]

[image: 2nd test case, 3 format are wrong]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Please use text blocks in your question, not images.

Comment: Try to extend the `NumberFormat`class and override the `format` method as `synchronized` to see the results.

Comment: Is the result consistent when running under single thread?

Comment: It is consistent when running under a single thread.

Comment: @elias This is working, very nice job ! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. I apologies for the little amount of detail I could provide. I don't really understand why copy() or new or even threadlocal didn't work as a way to make it thread safe, but well done.

Comment: This is puzzling. The official Javadoc says: "Number formats are generally not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally." But you _are_ creating separate format instances, aren't you? In that case, according to the docs, you shouldn't have to synchronize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the `NumberFormat` class and synchronize the `format` method:

```
class SynchronizedNumberFormat extends NumberFormat {

    public synchronized String format(Number number) {
        return super.format(number);
    }

    //unimplemented methods...

}
```

Comment: I can appreciate the desire to work around a problem like this, but this answer is a band-aid that is masking broken multi-threaded code. If you come across this question & answer having a similar issue, please know that it is **not** the right way to fix your problem.

Comment: @SeanBright Then maybe you could post an answer with the right procedure to do it?

Comment: Indeed I agree with the good practices, including the rejection of solutions that works, but it may not to be the best approach. However (while employee at a software company), sometimes the effort to refactor a big part of the application is not possible due time and/or architectural restrictions. And sometimes an "ugly" solution can efficiently solve the question. So, if a complete review of you code is possible, do it.

Comment: @Saffron I would love to, but you have yet to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There has never been any guarantee that a NumberFormat's `format` method will return exactly the same String as what you parsed the number from.  In fact, many Strings can yield the same Number value.

First, consider trailing zeroes:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number parsed = numberFormat.parse("1.500000000000");
String formatted = numberFormat.format(parsed);
System.out.println(formatted);      // prints 1.5
```

Second, NumberFormat doesn't parse a complete String like the Double.valueOf, Integer.valueOf, etc.  It parses as much as it can from the String, and ignores trailing characters.  The following are all valid operations that will parse successfully, without throwing a ParseException:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
numberFormat.parse("1.500000000000");
numberFormat.parse("1.5           ");
numberFormat.parse("1.5-----------");
numberFormat.parse("1.5helloworld");
```

All of the above calls return 1.5.

Comment: I'm not following how this relates to the question.

Comment: @SeanBright Notice the final line of code in the question's first code block: `format.equals(parse); //returns false sometimes` The question seems to be asking about this "inconsistency."

Comment: Sure. And then the screenshot allegedly shows `NumberFormat.format()` returning different outputs for the same input over multiple calls.

Comment: @VGR even without looking at the screenshots, your answer is still not representative of the OP's code. To rephrase, `Double.toString(numberFormat.parse("1.82")).equals("1.82")` is sometimes false.